# Disable warnings only on a project without modifying it

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio

I have a solution made of C# projects, where one of these is has some warnings.

This project is an open source project on github, that I've added as a submodule into the repository.

I know I can disable the warnings in this project by modifying the project file, but I have the objective to keep the submodule intact, as I only need to use it (avoiding to fork it and change the remote of the submodule) and want to see when that is updated from SourceTree (git GUI).

How can I disable warnings on that project without actually modifying it?

Comment: Why do you want to disable the warnings? Warnings mean something is possibly a problem. They're things you should fix or specifically disable with documented rationale, not sweep under the rug.

Comment: I dont think that you can disable the warnings without modifying the project file

Comment: @PhonicUK I agree, but I'm consuming that library as a user, I do not intend to fix it. I like the idea of having it as submodule, so I don't need to upload a compiled version of it.

Comment: Have you considered opening issues for these warnings on the github project?